# Get keyboard modifier when user click in toolbar command of safari extension

Tags: javascript, safari-extension

I want to get keyboard modifiers (like shift or option keys) when user click by toobar command of my safari extension.

In global HTML page I have next code:

```
safari.application.addEventListener("command", performCommand, false);

function performCommand(event)
{
    if (event.command === "foo") {

          //TODO: is shift pressed?
    }
}
```

Is it possible? Or may be exists any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, keyCode is not currently available on the command and validate events for toolbar items.
I submit enhancement request to apple.

Answer (score -1):

In Safari, you should be able to do:

```
if (event.shiftKey) {
  // Shift key was pressed...
}
```

Comment: Yes of course it works for regular events and pages. But in global HTML page and responding to commands from toolbar items the Event object don't have shiftKey property :-( http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/SafariExtensionCommandEventClassRef/SafariCommandEvent/SafariCommandEvent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009892

Comment: Dang, I thought that'd be an easy one.